# 'idx' not found only when knitting R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm attempting some differential expression analysis in R (using DESeq) and everything runs fine when I run the chunks manually.

However, upon knitting I get the following error for a specific chunk:

```
Quitting from lines 346-445 (Formatted_M1M2_miRNA_NP_AJ-copy.rmd) 
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'i' in selecting a method for function '[': object 'idx' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> [ -> .handleSimpleError -> h
Execution halted
```

This is the chunk:

```
ddsM1 = DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = countsM1, colData =  phenoM1_2, ~ pefull) 
ddsM1 <- estimateSizeFactors(ddsM1)
norm.ctsM1 <- counts(ddsM1, normalized=TRUE)

ddsM2 = DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = countsM2, colData =  phenoM2_2, ~ pefull) 
ddsM2 <- estimateSizeFactors(ddsM2)
norm.ctsM2 <- counts(ddsM1, normalized=TRUE)

mm_1 <- model.matrix(~ pefull, colData(ddsM1))
mm0_1 <- model.matrix(~ 1, colData(ddsM1))
norm.ctsM1 <- norm.ctsM1[rowSums(norm.ctsM1) > 0,]
fitM1 <- svaseq(norm.ctsM1, mod=mm_1, mod0=mm0_1, n.sv=2)
plot(fitM1$sv,pch=19,col="blue")

mm_2 <- model.matrix(~ pefull, colData(ddsM2))
mm0_2 <- model.matrix(~ 1, colData(ddsM2))
norm.ctsM2 <- norm.ctsM2[rowSums(norm.ctsM2) > 0,]
fitM2 <- svaseq(norm.ctsM2, mod=mm_2, mod0=mm0_2, n.sv=2)
plot(fitM2$sv,pch=19,col="blue")



ddsM1$SV1 <- fitM1$sv[,1]
ddsM1$SV2 <- fitM1$sv[,2]

phenoM1_2$SV1 <- fitM1$sv[,1]
phenoM1_2$SV2 <- fitM1$sv[,2]


ddsM2$SV1 <- fitM2$sv[,1]
ddsM2$SV2 <- fitM2$sv[,2]

phenoM2_2$SV1 <- fitM2$sv[,1]
phenoM2_2$SV2 <- fitM2$sv[,2]

###################

design= ~ pefull + SV1 + SV2
ddsM1_SV = DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = countsM1, colData =  phenoM1_2, design = design) 
ddsM2_SV = DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = countsM2, colData =  phenoM2_2, design = design)

ddsM1_SV <- ddsM1_SV[idx,]
ddsM1_2=DESeq(ddsM1_SV)
resultsNames(ddsM1_2)

ddsM2_SV <- ddsM2_SV[idx,]
ddsM2_2=DESeq(ddsM2_SV)
resultsNames(ddsM2_2)


ddsM2_SV <- ddsM2[idx,]
ddsM2_2=DESeq(ddsM2_SV)
resultsNames(ddsM2_2)

basemean=rowMeans(counts(ddsM1_2, normalized=TRUE))
basemean=rowMeans(counts(ddsM2_2, normalized=TRUE))


res0M1 <- results(ddsM1_2, alpha=0.05)
mcols(res0M1, use.names=TRUE)
summary(res0M1)
tabrM1=results(ddsM1_2, cooksCutoff=FALSE)


res0M2 <- results(ddsM2_2, alpha=0.05)
mcols(res0M2, use.names=TRUE)
summary(res0M2)
tabrM2=results(ddsM2_2, cooksCutoff=FALSE)

plotMA(res0M1, ylim=c(-7,7)) #Red points have adjusted p value < 0.1
plotMA(res0M2, ylim=c(-7,7))

#Estimating batches by svaseq followed by providing covariates in the DESeq design is expected to perform either equally good or better than adding batch as a factor in glm.. So design matrix for deseq could be something like:

#model.matrix(as.formula(paste0("~ genotype",fit))) #Why are you doing this?

resShrinkM1 = lfcShrink(ddsM1_2, coef=2)
plotMA(resShrinkM1, ylim=c(-5,5))

resShrinkM2 = lfcShrink(ddsM2_2, coef=2)
plotMA(resShrinkM2, ylim=c(-5,5))

#filtering results
resSigM1 <- subset(res0M1, pvalue < 0.05)
resSigM1


resSigM2 <- subset(res0M2, pvalue < 0.05)
resSigM2

rownames(resSigM1)
rownames(resSigM2)

head(res0M1[order(res0M1$padj),], 5) # order by padjusted and print the top 5
head(res0M2[order(res0M2$padj),], 5) 

resLFC1 = results(ddsM1_2, lfcThreshold = 1) #genes with a fold change of 2 (or -2) - i.e.doubling/halving.
summary(resLFC1)

resLFC2 = results(ddsM2_2, lfcThreshold = 1) #genes with a fold change of 2 (or -2) - i.e.doubling/halving.
summary(resLFC2)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ```object 'idx' not found``` Check your variable's name

Comment: That's not the problem since it runs just fine when I run it manually, even after clearing my environment

Comment: Can you add  object ```idx``` to your question? Otherwise we can't run your code.

Comment: You never assign 'idx' in the code above